How to Run Post-Install Commands Silently Using Inno Setup?
I'm using Inno Setup to create an installer for my application. Part of the installation process includes installing the Ollama binary and running a couple of commands to set up models. However, the commands do not seem to run as expected. Here is my Inno Setup script:
[Setup]
AppName=Chat2Find
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\Chat2Find
DefaultGroupName=Chat2Find
OutputDir=.
OutputBaseFilename=Chat2FindInstaller
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
DiskSpanning=yes

[Files]
; Include the executable
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\Chat2Find.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

; Include the GGUF files to be extracted to a permanent location
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.3.Q4_K_M.gguf"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\Phi-3-mini-4k-instruct-q4.gguf"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

; Include the Ollama setup binary
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\OllamaSetup.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: ignoreversion deleteafterinstall

; Include other resources
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\menu.png"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\close.png"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\new_note.jpg"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\copy.png"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\send_icon.png"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\chat2find.jpeg"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\Chat2Find"; Filename: "{app}\Chat2Find.exe"
Name: "{commondesktop}\Chat2Find"; Filename: "{app}\Chat2Find.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "Create a &desktop icon"; GroupDescription: "Additional icons:"; Flags: checkedonce

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\Chat2Find.exe"; Description: "Launch Chat2Find"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
; Run Ollama setup silently
Filename: "{tmp}\OllamaSetup.exe"; Description: "Install Ollama"; Flags: waituntilterminated

; Run Ollama commands silently using a script
Filename: "cmd.exe"; Parameters: "/C {app}\run_ollama_commands.bat"; Flags: runhidden postinstall

[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  GGUFDir: String;
  MistralDef, Phi3Def, OllamaScript: String;
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    GGUFDir := ExpandConstant('{app}');
    
    if not DirExists(GGUFDir) then
    begin
      CreateDir(GGUFDir);
    end;
    
    MistralDef := GGUFDir + '\mistral_definition';
    SaveStringToFile(MistralDef,
      'FROM ' + GGUFDir + '\Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.3-Q4_K_M.gguf' + #13#10 +
      'TEMPLATE """[INST] {{ if .System }}{{ .System }} {{ end }}{{ .Prompt }} [/INST]"""' + #13#10 +
      'PARAMETER stop "[INST]"' + #13#10 +
      'PARAMETER stop "[/INST]"', False);

    Phi3Def := GGUFDir + '\phi3_definition';
    SaveStringToFile(Phi3Def,
      'FROM ' + GGUFDir + '\Phi-3-mini-4k-instruct-q4.gguf' + #13#10 +
      'TEMPLATE """<s>{{ if .Prompt }}' + #13#10 +
      '{{ .Prompt }}' + #13#10 +
      '{{ end }}' + #13#10 +
      '{{ .Response }}"""' + #13#10 +
      'PARAMETER stop' + #13#10 +
      'PARAMETER stop' + #13#10 +
      'PARAMETER stop' + #13#10 +
      'PARAMETER num_ctx 4096', False);

    OllamaScript := GGUFDir + '\run_ollama_commands.bat';
    SaveStringToFile(OllamaScript,
      'ollama create C2F_mistral -f "' + MistralDef + '"' + #13#10 +
      'ollama create C2F_phi3 -f "' + Phi3Def + '"', False);
  end;
end;


Problem:
The commands in run_ollama_commands.bat do not seem to execute as expected. How can I ensure that these commands run silently after the installation of the Ollama binary?
Additional Context:
The OllamaSetup.exe installs the Ollama binary correctly.
I need the models to be created using the GGUF files and templates provided during the installation.
The batch file (run_ollama_commands.bat) should run silently without showing a command prompt window.
Any insights or suggestions on how to correctly execute these post-install commands would be greatly appreciated!

This site helps you to fix a problem with the code you have written to perform a specific task. You appear to be asking about how to perform a specific task using code. For that reason this site is not an appropriate platform for you at this current time.

@Compo If you don’t know anything about this question, just be direct and say that you don’t know. Don’t beat around the bush and find excuses.

This site helps to fix a programming code issue. I have read your question and it is asking us how to run post install commands from inno setup. You are therefore wanting usage research information rather than help to fix something you have already coded. (As a side note, you are not going to push me to give you an answer to an off topic question with your comment above, and you are unlikely to motivate others to do so).

If you're using Inno Setup and need to execute post-install commands silently, follow these steps to ensure everything runs smoothly. Here’s a refined solution:

Update Your Inno Setup Script:

Remove the [Code] section that creates the definition files and batch script dynamically. Instead, manually prepare these files and include them in your installer. Here’s how you should modify your Inno Setup script:
[Setup]
AppName=Chat2Find
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\Chat2Find
DefaultGroupName=Chat2Find
OutputDir=.
OutputBaseFilename=Chat2FindInstaller
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
DiskSpanning=yes

[Files]
; Include the executable
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\Chat2Find.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

; Include the GGUF files
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.3.Q4_K_M.gguf"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\Phi-3-mini-4k-instruct-q4.gguf"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

; Include pre-created definition files
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\mistral_definition"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\phi3_definition"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

; Include the Ollama setup binary
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\OllamaSetup.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: ignoreversion deleteafterinstall

; Include the batch file
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\run_ollama_commands.bat"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

; Include other resources
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\menu.png"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\close.png"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\new_note.jpg"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\copy.png"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\send_icon.png"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\presh\c2f\dist\chat2find.jpeg"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\Chat2Find"; Filename: "{app}\Chat2Find.exe"
Name: "{commondesktop}\Chat2Find"; Filename: "{app}\Chat2Find.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "Create a &desktop icon"; GroupDescription: "Additional icons:"; Flags: checkedonce

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\OllamaSetup.exe"; Description: "Install Ollama"; Flags: waituntilterminated runhidden

; Run Ollama commands silently
Filename: "{app}\run_ollama_commands.bat"; Parameters: ""; Flags: waituntilterminated runhidden

Filename: "{app}\Chat2Find.exe"; Description: "Launch Chat2Find"; Flags: postinstall


Prepare the Batch File:

Create a run_ollama_commands.bat file with the following content. This file should be included in your installer:
@echo off
cd /d %~dp0
echo Running Ollama commands...

ollama create C2F_mistral -f mistral_definition
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
    echo Failed to create C2F_mistral model
    exit /b %errorlevel%
)

ollama create C2F_phi3 -f phi3_definition
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
    echo Failed to create C2F_phi3 model
    exit /b %errorlevel%
)

echo Ollama commands executed successfully. Deleting GGUF files...

del /f /q "Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.3.Q4_K_M.gguf"
del /f /q "Phi-3-mini-4k-instruct-q4.gguf"

echo GGUF files deleted.
exit

Explanation:
The @echo off command suppresses the command output to avoid clutter. (Inno Setup also runs it silently)
cd /d %~dp0 changes the directory to where the batch file is located.
Commands are run with error checking, and any errors are reported.
GGUF files are deleted after successful command execution.
By following these instructions, you'll ensure that your post-install commands run silently and efficiently.

Please do not post a batch file content as a solution without including the content of it pre-solution in your question. We have no idea if you have changed anything in that file, and it was absolutely impossible for any person but you to know that. Creating a question for a comnunity, but not offering them sufficient detail to answer it, is not community friendly.

Your self-answer looks like a set of instructions on how to perform a task using a particular toolset. It is a reference tutorial, and whilst it may be useful to somebody, it is not on topic for this site. Here we deal with a single, specific, and reproducible problem with your submitted programning code, given a [mcve] of it, and sufficient debugging, environment, and execution, information.
